# rpm -V inner workings

Tags: linux, rpm, hashsum

I have an `rpm` file that is used to install a package I made the package consists of java classes and shell scripts to run these java classes, in a `.run` file. So the rpm essentially only contains a `foo.run` which installs all the contents of the package. My question is then when I run the `rpm -V` command to verify that the `rpm package` has not become corrupt, will it be only verifying if the `foo.run` file has not become corrupt or if `foo.class` and `foo.sh` installed from the `foo.run` contained in the `rpm package` has not become corrupt?

Answer (score 1):

When you run `rpm -V packagename` all files installed by `packagename` on your computer will be compared against the metadata in the RPM itself. The RPM itself has information about each file in the RPM (like md5sum, file size, permissions, owner, etc).

So, if your RPM contains the files `foo.class` or `foo.sh` then yes, those files will be verified.

If your script simply downloads those files from the internet when the script is run, then no, those files won't be verified because when the RPM was created no information about those files was stored.

Put another way: if you run `rpm -qpl filename.rpm` all the files listed there will be verified when you run `rpm -V packagename` because those are the files RPM knows about.